# How to add taxonomy term reference field in a custom drupal form

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, forms

A menu item is defined with `drupal_get_form` as callback function and returning the form from call back function. How can I add `taxonomy_term_reference` field to this form?

```
$items['files/add'] = array(
      'title' => 'Add file',
      'description' => 'Allows users to add files',
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('mymodule_add_file'),
      'access callback' => TRUE,
    );
function mymodule_add_file($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_title("Add file");
    $form['mymodule_form'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#tree' => TRUE,
      '#collapsable' => FALSE,
      '#title' => 'Adding file to locker room',
    );

    $form['mymodule_form']['file'] = array(
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#title' => 'Upload file',      
    );

    $form['mymodule_form']['tag'] = array(
      '#type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference',
      '#title' => 'Tags',
    );  

    return $form;
}
```

I am not sure how to add taxonomy_term_reference field for `$form['mymodule_form']['tag']` . I want this field to be a text field with auto complete from a vocabulary terms and new term to be added when entered term is not found

Answer (score 5):

For Drupal 7, the code is something like this, where `field_tags` is a taxonomy field in the node with widget type autocomplete.

```
<?php
   $node=node_load($nid);
    $tags = array();
    foreach ($node->field_tags['und'] as $item) {
      $tags[$item['tid']] = isset($item['taxonomy_term']) ?  $item['taxonomy_term'] : taxonomy_term_load($item['tid']);
    }
    $form['tags'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => taxonomy_implode_tags($tags),
      '#title' => 'Add Tags',
      '#autocomplete_path' => 'taxonomy/autocomplete/field_tags',
      '#maxlength' => 1024,
      '#element_validate' => array('taxonomy_autocomplete_validate')
    );
?>
```

Comment: what is `page` doing at the end of your code? seams to my like invalid php code?

Comment: That appears to be just a typo. You can safely ignore it, I believe.

Comment: With the $form part of the code above, I get the taxonomy field to show up in the form. Autocompletion also works. But how do I store the submitted values in the taxonomy field of a node? `$submitted_tags = $form_state['values']['tags']; $node->field_tags[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $submitted_tags;` doesn't work for me. Just gives me errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the vocabulary id - you should be able to hardcode it so either

```
$form['mymodule_form']['tag'][$vocabulary->vid] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => $typed_string,
  '#maxlength' => 100,
  '#autocomplete_path' => 'taxonomy/autocomplete/'. $vocabulary->vid,
  '#required' => $vocabulary->required,
  '#title' => $vocabulary->name,
  '#description' => t('Some description ...").')
```

);

or for vocab id 5

```
$form['mymodule_form']['tag']['5'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => $typed_string,
  '#maxlength' => 100,
  '#autocomplete_path' => 'taxonomy/autocomplete/5',
  '#required' => $vocabulary->required,
  '#title' => $vocabulary->name,
  '#description' => t('Some description ...").')
);
```

Not tested, but that should work. Else have a gander here: http://drupal.org/node/854216

Comment: Are you sure this works for D7 as well? I couldnt get it working. It gives exception in taxonomy.module

Comment: hmm, yes it works, but not exactly the way it should.

Comment: This won't work. Drupal 7's taxonomy_autocomplete requires a field name to be passed as an argument. This example uses Drupal 6's taxonomy autocomplete syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I used this and I got autocomplete callbacks working, however not for the specified taxonomy vocab. Instead it returned results from all vocabs

```
  $element['test'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['test']) ? $items[$delta]['test'] : NULL,
      '#maxlength' => 100,
      '#autocomplete_path' => 'taxonomy/autocomplete/37',
   );
```

I'm not quite sure why that is to be honest.

Comment: I tried similarly and below exception is given SELECT t.tid AS tid,t.name AS name FROM {taxonomy_term_data} t WHERE (t.vid IN ()) AND t.name LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_0 ESCAPE &#039;\\&#039;) LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0; Array([:db_condition_placeholder_0]=&gt;%imag%)
and mysql is giving exception near &#039;\\&#039;) LIMIT OFFSET 0&#039;

Answer (score 0):

@tecjam
 For Drupal 7, you almost had it. All you have to do is use the field name instead of the vocab id.

Like this:

```
 $element['test'] = array(
 '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['test']) ? $items[$delta]['test'] : NULL,
  '#maxlength' => 100,
  '#autocomplete_path' => 'taxonomy/autocomplete/field_name',
);
```

Replace field_name with the name of your field.